# Problems Exporting to excel via VBA or Macro

Tags: excel, vba, windows, ms-access, export-to-excel

Recently ran into a problem exporting data from access into excel.
Suddenly i started getting kind of random errors. Sometimes it exports an empty excel file with a strange sheet name like :"A266FF2A662E84b639DA".
The most common error is a popup saying "External Table is not in the expected format", when i click the help button it takes me to this page: [Help Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-formaterror-3274?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(jeterr40.chm5003274)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)
If i export the data manually everything works fine.

Thanks in advance

Already tried changing multiple privacy options, both in Access and Excel. Changed the expor location and tried remaking the code, all with no success

Comment: What code? Have you step debugged?

Comment: It is more than one situation, using a simple macro to run a saved export throws an error. and we are also using this code for example:  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, query, caminhoFinal

Comment: Edit question to show data and code. Consider posting to a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It was solved with a company windows update, Thank you for the help